# If you try to validate the same iTunes IAP receipt twice, will the second time fail?

Tags: ios, validation, in-app-purchase, receipt

I have a question about Apple's Receipt Validation service (as described here): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1

My question is: If you try to validate the same legitimate receipt twice, will the second validation attempt fail? Perhaps Apple's receipt validation servers would interpret this as attempting to foil receipt validation by using the same receipt twice? But I do not know. I have a situation where my servers are reporting 100% of IAP receipts invalid, and I'm trying to figure out why. I don't think they are 100% are invalid.

I learned that the company we are partnering with is also validating these IAP receipts, and I'm fairly certain that their validation call will get made before ours does. So I'm wondering if their validation call "uses" the receipt, thus causing ours to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the second attempt will not fail. We actually tried this and were able to get status=0 (i.e. receipt is valid) multiple times submitting the same receipt.

Comment: Can you validate the same receipt after a year? Is there a timeframe?

Comment: I do not know if there is a timeframe.